# "[[17~^" is auto added in terminal

Tags: keyboard, gnome-terminal, text-editor, flicker

When I open the terminal and press 6, it start typing "[[17~^" automatically and it continues. I also noticed that sometime it starts without pressing 6 or any key. Additional issue to that, In my browser search bar/ text editor, it starts flickering and If I press any key then it stops. How to solve this? I have tried multiple times by unstalling and reinsatlling the ubuntu. Currently I am using 18.04. It would be a great help If any genius out there can help to solve this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[[17~^` should appear in your terminal emulator when you press <kbd>F6</kbd>. The same key has functionality related to focusing the address bar in Firefox and Chromium.

Sounds like hardware error, your keyboard generating spurious keypresses.